# SSAS - MDX - Read multiple attributes from a dimension

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, adventureworks

For example, taking into account the Adventure Works database, I would like to display on rows the hierarchy of accounts and on columns i would like to show "Account Type" property.

This MDX shows an "#Error" on the Account Type column:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Account Type] AS [Account].[Accounts].[Account Type].CurrentMember.Name 
SELECT
    {[Measures].[Account Type]} ON 0,   
    (
        [Account].[Accounts].Members
    ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Any idea how this can be improved?

Answer (score 0):

If you execute your query in Management Studio and either hover the mouse over the "#ERROR" or double click a cell showing "#ERROR", the error message is shown, which states that you use an element expression for `CurrentMember` while it was expecting an hierarchy. You should use

```
[Account].[Accounts].CurrentMember.Properties("Account Type", TYPED)
```

instead of

```
[Account].[Accounts].[Account Type].CurrentMember.Name
```

to access properties. In this specific case, the second argument to `Properties` can be omitted, as it states that the result should be returned as the data type of the property (e. g. integer or date). But here, the original is a string anyway, hence you could simply use

```
[Account].[Accounts].CurrentMember.Properties("Account Type")
```

which always returns the property as string, independent of its type.